# get nested img src from $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

for one of these simple CMS I need to pass the src from an  tag to the background-image url of the parent div. With definite id's everything works as is should, but now I'm trying to automate it, and it just won't work. Though I'm quite sure it should be some syntax error, I'm quite new to Java. Thanks in advance 4 any hints! :)

This is my code so far:

```js
      var imageUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
      console.log(imageUrl)

      $('.background-image').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="background-image">
  <img src="myimg1.jpg" class="imgtag">
</div>

<div class="background-image">
  <img src="myimg2.jpg" class="imgtag">
</div>

<div class="background-image">
  <img src="myimg3.jpg" class="imgtag">
</div>
```

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: `I'm quite new to Java.` javascript? or java. both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work... except `this` may not be be what you think it is. If `$(this)` is called from within something like a `click` event, `this` will be set to the element that was clicked, so it'd have to contain the images.

If it isn't being called from there, then `this` probably refers to the window, which isn't really what you want either. Probably just:

```
var imageUrl = $('#some-container').find('img').attr('src');
```

is what you want, with `#some-container` being some parent element of the images that you can target.

If you want to apply this to multiple elements in a parent, you can use something like this:

```
$('#some-parent').find('img').each(image => {
    let imageUrl = $(image).attr('src');
    // do something with imageUrl
});
```

It'll loop through every `img` that is inside of `#some-parent` and you can perform the actual you need on all them with a few lines of code.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? Based on they have, I'd be willing to bet that `this` is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution works fine, but I'd have to add one line for every image on the website and there's gonna be some :) So do you have any idea how to automate this? So that in every '.background-image' container the img will be found and the src passed to the background url of the container. 
Also I cannot explain the downvote, I found your answer very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to the first comment I'm beginning to understand the meaning of $(this) :) So I got this working using the .each function, my final java snippet looks like this now:

```js
$(".full-image").each(function() {
   var imageUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
   console.log(imageUrl)
   $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
  });
```

Comment: Thats not Java. Thats JavaScript. The two are very different things.